# SQL Distinct column with additional info from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

Getting better with SQL so my apologies if this is dead simple.

If I add a DISTINCT keyword to a query I'm going to get a DISTINCT row, but what if I just want a single DISTINCT column with other columns from that row joined on it.

For instance

```
id | name | comment
-------------------------------
1  | John | Happy Holidays!
2  | Bill | Merry Christmas!
3  | Dave | Happy New Year!
4  | John | Happy Thanksgiving!
5  | John | Happy Holidays!
6  | Dave | Happy Thanksgiving!
```

On this table, running `SELECT DISTINCT name, comment` would give me:

```
John | Happy Holidays!
Bill | Merry Christmas!
Dave | Happy New Year!
John | Happy Thanksgiving!
Dave | Happy Thanksgiving!
```

However, I want **just** DISTINCT by name, and then whatever comment belongs to that record.  So my result would be:

```
John | Happy Holidays!
Bill | Merry Christmas!
Dave | Happy New Year!
```

The other John and Dave comments would be fine too, I don't care which one I get so long as the names are DISTINCT.

My original thought was to join the comments after:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name, b.comment FROM userComments a JOIN userComments b ON a.id = b.id
```

but the DISTINCT is still operating on the comment as well.

Comment: `DISTINCT` always operates on the whole rowset. Do you just want the unique names, along with _any one_ comment, or something like _the first_ comment by `id`? ('distinct' isn't really the right term)

Comment: Yes, unique names along with *any one* comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit this to the *first* listed comment per user `name`, you really need to apply a `MIN()` aggregate to the `id` and use that to join back against the whole table.  You could also use `MAX(id)`.

```
SELECT 
  userComments.name,
  userComments.comment
FROM
  userComments
  JOIN (
    SELECT name, 
      MIN(id) AS id
    FROM userComments
    GROUP BY name
  ) one_comment ON userComments.id = one_comment.id
```

Here's a demonstration. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8e0c/3

If you wanted to do it alphabetically by sorting the comments, you could also use `MAX(comment)` or `MIN(comment)` but then you would need to perform the join across both columns to identify uniquely:

```
ON one_comment.comment = userComments.comment AND one_comment.name = userComments.name
```

Answer (score 2):

Group by name to get a single record for the given name.

```
SELECT a.name, b.comment 
FROM   userComments a JOIN userComments b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.name;
```

NOTE: this is not deterministic and will pull the comment from an indeterminate matching row.

Comment: MySQL will permit this where most other RDBMS won't (since `comment` is not in the `GROUP BY`) but it gives no control over which `comment` is returned.  It will be indeterminate.

Comment: This actually answers the OP's question, which explicitly says that the comment can be any of the comments.  I would emphasize that the `comment` comes from an indeterminate matching row (and there is no way to control for that).

Comment: I added that disclaimer to my answer.